# Problems with parallelization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I can't figure out the problem in the following short script which should compare a single CPU computation with a parallelization concerning computation time.

[image: parfor]
Link to full image: [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvDQt.jpg)

The code is:

```
n = 700;
ranksSingle = zeros(1,n);
tic
for ind = 1:n
    ranksSingle(ind) = rank(magic(ind));
end
toc

matlabpool local 4
tic
ranks = zeros(1,n);
parfor (ind = 1:n)
    ranks(ind) = rank(magic(ind));
end
toc
isequal(ranksSingle, ranks)
matlabpool close
```

I also tried it with `matlabpool 2`. As you can clearly see from the process window, all cores are busy to 100% when running the parallel computation (marked red).

When running the single-cpu computation (marked blue), strangly the 4 cores are also more busy than before. I would have expected only ONE core to go up. I searched the internet to see, if perhaps the `magic()` or `rank` function are built-in parallelized, but as you can read from here: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1894 it's not the case. So it's okay that those 4 cores are not fully busy, but still I'm wondering why ALL cores go up.

Secondly, I really wonder the computation time of the parallelized version. I know there's some sort of overhead by distributing the jobs to the single cores, but this shouldn't be so high that there's no benefit at all in the end :(

Perhaps anybody can tell me something about it :( I'm really stuck at this since I want to speed up some of my for-loops. Second question is, if there's any command to always set the worker size to the number of physical cores I have in my computer? (and also using Hyper Threading if that's an additional benefit?)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to run a parallel job, you should remember that it's bad to have too many fast iterations, and that it's bad to have too few slow iterations. If you do a million iterations that each take a few miliseconds, the overhead from parallelization will destroy any possible gain. If you do nine iterations that take an hour each, and you run it on eight processors in parallel, seven processors will be idling for an hour waiting for iteration #9 to finish.

Thus, your example is pretty bad for testing the impact of parallelization, because both `magic` and `rank` are way too fast.

```
    function testParfor2
    tic
    for i=1:4
        pause(1); %# wait for 1 second
    end
    toc
    matlabpool open 4
    tic
    parfor i=1:4
        pause(1); %# wait for 1 second
    end
    toc

Elapsed time is 4.050287 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.534534 seconds.
```

Note that I was running a second parallel job at the same time, but roughly, the result should be reproducible: There is a bit of overhead (note that I didn't count the time used by `matlabpool`!), but the speed-up is there. You should be seeing the same amount of overhead if you increase the pause length. Also, you should be testing with your actual loops (try to parallelize the outermost loop, btw).

To your second question:

```
 matlabpool open
```

Will create as many workers as there are physical cores. Hyperthreading will help you ensure that the computer remains responsive when the parallel job is running.

Finally, while `magic` and `rank` may not be fully multithreaded by themselves, they may make calls to multithreaded routines.

Comment: Correct. For example, `rank` uses `svd`, which is multithreaded.

Comment: Okay thanks, so I'll try it with some more costly operations tomorrow :)

Comment: @Jonas: `matlabpool open` gives me: "Starting matlabpool using the 'local' configuration ... connected to 2 labs.". As you can see clearly from my screenshot above, I have 4 cores, thus that's apperently NOT the expected outcome!? EDIT: Somehow I can't start `matlabpool(4)`, I'm getting:  You requested a minimum of 4 workers, but the scheduler's ClusterSize property is currently set to allow a maximum of 2 workers.  To run a parallel job on more workers than this,increase the ClusterSize property setting in the 'local' configuration using the Configurations Manager [...].

Comment: @ColHeather: Have you tried setting the default number of workers in the Configurations Manager in the "parallel" menu?

Comment: @Jonas: Yeah I now have set the ClusterSize to 4 and it works now pretty well! But I'm somehow a bit confused... I thought it would be possible without any user interference to automatically use ALL of the cores. But like this, when disrtibuting my code, the user would have to adjust the clustersize on himself :(

Comment: @ColHeather: I'm really surprised that you had to edit the configuration. I have been using the parallel processing toolbox on multiple machines on Linux, Windows and Mac, and it always went to the maximum # of cores by default. I suggest you contact MathWorks to inform them about a possible bug.